# Copying large numbers of files over the internet with C# Web Api

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api2, file-transfer

Our web site allows administrators to select file source and destinations for syncing. The source will be a SFTP server and the destination will be an AWS S3 bucket. The web site will create queued jobs in SQL server that will, at some point, be picked up by the service.

My quandary is that there could be 10 + scheduled jobs with 250,000 or more files. Not only do I need to copy the files, I also need to parse a manifest file that contains meta information for each file; to be stored in SQL. The files will be relatively small, 25Mb or less in most cases. I want to avoid the service constantly running and never being able to "catch up"

I'm thinking of creating a new thread for each job. No 2 jobs will be writing to the same location, so I don't think disk thrashing will be an issue.  I'd appreciate and helpful advice on the best approach.

Also, I'm using Web Api because we are exposing other related functionality to customers and internal applications.

Comment: This sounds like more of an S3 question than a C# Web Api question to me.  Do you suspect the bottleneck will be the transfer or the insertion?  Because that makes a difference.

Comment: It's really more the cumulative process that concerns me. Transfering the file, inserting into S3, recording the meta data, and deleting the existing file. Given the potential number of queued jobs x the potential number of files I'm concerned that there just isn't enough off-peak time to complete it all. At least not one at a time.  I forgot to mention that we won't have a server dedicated to this. It will run on our web server so it needs to run at night as to not consume resources needed by the website

Comment: I'm wondering if putting the IIS app in the middle is a good idea.  I'm pretty ignorant of AWS, but wouldn't it be better to have the data pulled by that side, rather than pushed by IIS?  If you could somehow stage the data once it arrives in a pre-process state and then process it in bulk on AWS.  Doing this one at a time seems problematic.  One way to address performance issues is to break it down to individual steps and reduce/eliminate bottlenecks in each one.

Comment: Definitely something to think on. Thanks